# How to change User Table in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.0.

I have `user` table in my DB.

I changed table variables in `User` and `Config/Auth` to `user` but when I try to register Laravel gives me an error:

```
Table 'xxxx.crmx_users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `xxxx` where `email` = xxx
```

What I do wrong? Why Laravel is still looking for `userS` table?

Comment: do you have prefixes in your database ?

Comment: @KhanShahrukh, yes, I have 'crmx_' prefix. But anything else works correct.

Comment: You may try `php artisan dump-autoload` to regenerate autoload compiled file. I am not sure will it help or not, but give it a try.

Comment: @ArifulHaque, maybe you mean php composer dump-autoload?
I've tried but it does not help. It seems to me that problem is with the cache.

Comment: Ahh.. ya I mean composer.. thinking something, writing something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `app\Services\Registrar.php` file, and in `validator()` function.

```
public function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }
```

Change

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:YOUR_TABLE_NAME',
```

I believe this will solve your problem.

Comment: lol, how I should know this. No any word in docs))) thanks a lot!